# Как вывести нечетные числа из интервала по ростом и парные числа по убыванию?

Tags: java

Вот мой код

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String start;
        String exit;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter start interval");
        start = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter exit interval");
        exit = scanner.nextLine();

        int totalOddNumbers = 0;
        int totalEvenNumbers = 0;

        for (int i = Integer.parseInt(start); i <= Integer.parseInt(exit); i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                totalOddNumbers += i;
                System.out.println("Odd Number = " + i);

            }
//            else{
//                totalEvenNumbers += i;
//                System.out.println("Even Number = " + i);
//            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum - " + totalOddNumbers);
//      System.out.println("Sum - " + totalEvenNumbers);

    }
```

- Пользователь вводит интервал (например, [1, 12]).
- Программа выводит на экран нечетные числа из интервала по ростом и парные числа по убыванию.
- Програма виводить на екран суму непарних та парних чисел.

Comment: в чем проблема то? Ваш код не работает? Что в нем не работает?

Comment: Как вывести нечетные числа из интервала по ростом и парные числа по убыванию? Вот мой вопрос. Не знаю как реализовать

Comment: что такое `по ростом` и что такое `парные числа`? Ваш код уже что то выводит, что в этом выводе не так?

Comment: по возрастанию* а парные числа это 2 4 6 8 10...
Мой код выводит суму непарних та парних чисел. А мне надо вывести нечетные числа из интервала по возрастанию и парные числа по убыванию

Comment: вам надо иметь 2 цикла - один пусть идет по возрастанию, второй по убыванию. В пераом цикле выводите нечетные числа, во втором - четные.